# NodeJS one route working another giving 404

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

Currently I am building a small API with NodeJS, using Express.

Within the Index.js I have created my routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const cors=require("cors");

const clientsController = require('../clients/controllers/ClientsController');

//'/api/clients',
router.get('/', clientsController.index);

router.options('/create', cors())
router.post('/create', clientsController.create);

router.options('/nuevo', cors())
router.get('/nuevo', clientsController.nuevo);

module.exports = router;
```

Those routes has been configured under App.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

// importamos el archivo router de cada modulo, en este caso le pusimos index
var productsRouter = require('./app/products/index')
var clientsRouter = require('./app/clients/index')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

//creamos una ruta padre que debe usarse siempre, agregandole el resto de la ruta, la ruta siempre va a iniciar con /api/productos
app.use('/api/products', productsRouter);
app.use('/api/clients', clientsRouter);
```

When accessing route `/api/clients` it will trigger the following method on the controller which does actually return a json on the browser.

```
module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {

    const clients = await prisma.Clients.findMany();

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    res.json({
        clients
    });

}
```

As a test I have created the route `/nuevo` however when calling `/api/clients/nuevo` I got an error stating that the route is not found

NotFoundError: Not Found
at /home/taqueria/app.js:36:8
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/taqueria/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/taqueria/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /home/taqueria/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/home/taqueria/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/home/taqueria/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at /home/taqueria/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
at next (/home/taqueria/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
at Function.handle (/home/taqueria/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at router (/home/taqueria/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)

But both routes are exactly the same, adding the full clientController

```
const {
    PrismaClient
} = require('@prisma/client');

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {

    const clients = await prisma.Clients.findMany();

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    res.json({
        clients
    });

}

module.exports.create = async (req, res) => {

    let msg = ""
    let data = {}
    let errorMsg = ""
    let status = ""

    try {
        const newClient = await prisma.clients.create({
            data: req.body,

        });

        msg = "Cliente creado"
        data = newClient
        console.log(newClient);
        status = newClient && newClient.id > 0 ? true : false

    } catch (error) {

        errorMsg = "Error de tipo " + error + " consulte con el administrador"
    }


    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    res.json({

        "status": status,
        "msg": msg,
        "data": data,
        "errorMsg": errorMsg

    });

}

module.exports.nuevo = async (req, res) => {
    
    const clients = await prisma.Clients.findMany();

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    res.json({
        clients
    });

}
```

Does anyone what might cause one route to work and other, exactly the same dont?

Thank you

Comment: `NotFoundError: Not Found at /home/taqueria/app.js:36` your are showing us this line. It look like an error that you throw in the code.

Comment: Thank you madflow, you are seeing the node app error handling system

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

Comment: Please update your question with all the code. I meant to say "you are *not* showing us this line".

Comment: I have figure it out. As I started my server without Nodemon, I had to manually restart the server to the new routes to take effect.